# Como impedir que un programa se pueda cerrar mediante la X de CMD en python

Tags: python

Tengo un programa en python el cual quiero que no se pueda cerrar mediante la X de CMD, solo mediante la acción del usuario. Lo que me gustaría es detectar cuando el usuario cierra mediante la X para volver a lanzar el programa tipo lo siguiente:

```
try:
        client.loop_forever()

except KeyboardInterrupt: #ctrl + C para salir
        print("cerrando...")
        

except: # aqui me gustaría detectar el cierre mediante la X de CMD
        print("reiniciando...")
        os.system('python "C:/code/myscript.py"')
```

¿Cómo puedo detectarlo o impedir que se cierre el CMD? Gracias.

Comment: ¿Entiendes que el *CMD* (como lo llamas) es un entorno sobre el que se ejecuta tu *script* y por lo tanto no tienes control sobre el mismo de la forma que pretendes?. Por otro lado, que mala experiencia para un usuario el intentar cerrar un programa y que el mismo se vuelva a ejecutar sólo porque le da la gana. ¿Cómo salgo del programa? Lo que tratas de hacer no sería del todo correcto, IMHO. Saludos

Comment: Es un script que utilizo para un servicio que ejecuto al inicio de un servidor (windows) con un fichero .bat, y alguna vez sin darme cuenta lo he cerrado sin querer cuando estoy trabajando con otra cosa, con esto quiero asegurarme de que no pueda cerrarlo por un descuido

Comment: A ver a ver... si yo abro Chrome... este tiene un botón de cierre como aplicación... dando igual que este haciendo yo dentro... si apreto esa X de arriba a la derecha, este tratará de cerrarse. Entonces... si tu vas, y cierras lo que está ejecutando tu código... el código se detendrá. Pero no puedes hacer que cmd detecte que estás tratando de cerrar la aplicacion. Son cosas muy distintas.

Comment: Lo mejor que podrías conseguir, es ocultar la misma ejecución del CMD, para que tu dedo no resbale justo encima de la X y termines cerrando tu ejecucion... tienes 2 opciones... lo ejecutas y lo mandas a donde no lo veas (windows 10 tiene multiples escritorios por ejemplo) o le agregas un comando para ocultarlo, y solo podrías frenarlo del administrador de tareas

Comment: Si es un servicio no debería ser visible. Existen muchas formas de programar un servicio en segundo plano. Saludos

Comment: Creo que la primera forma, dejar el cmd en un escritorio a parte, te dejaría poder ver la ejecucion, en caso de que necesites verla.... para la 2do, encontre esto -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13763134/disabling-the-cmd-close-button-by-batch-command

Comment: no se si me estoy explicando bien.. trato de encontrar algún evento o función que detecte el cierre del programa, ya sea para volverlo a ejecutar o para lo que puede ser por ejemplo la creación de un log de cuando se ha cerrado, no que CMD detecte nada, simplemente que cuando se cierre el programa (mediante una u otra forma) se pueda realizar una acción.

Comment: lo ejecuto en un CMD por que está en desarrollo y me gusta comprobar de vez en cuando el funcionamiento.

Comment: El CMD solo se encarga de ejecutar el programa, no tienes control sobre este, lo mejor que puedes hacer es ejecutarlo en segundo plano, es lo típico para los servicios

Comment: Si sigues por esa línea, lo siguiente que vas a querer es detectar cuando intenta matar el proceso en el administrador de tareas, y después cuando lanza `taskkill` para matar el proceso.  Si el código pertenece a un servicio, entonces programa un servicio.

Comment: En lugar de hacer que la ventana de cmd no se pueda cerrar, que tal si cambias la extensión de tu archivo de .py a .pyw que hace que no se muestre la ventana de cmd?